# Equality of segments of a circumscribed circle in a equilateral triangle

Tags: geometry, proof-writing

"Consider an equilateral triangle $ABC$ and $P$ a point on the arc $BC$ of its circumscribed circle."

Show that:

$AP = BP + CP$

PS: It's not intended for using trigonometry. I don't know why but without trigonometry i don't see any way to prove this. Any clues?

Comment: Hint: Apply Ptolemy's theorem.

Comment: Well, that's all. Thanks you. With Ptolemy's theorem is solved.